# Accessing an Apple Numbers with JavaScript run thru Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, spreadsheet

I have a JavaScript that works with tables in an Apple Numbers spreadsheet when run from Apples script editor.  I needed to add file reading functionality to the script so I moved to Visual Studio Code and Node.js.  The file reading now works but this line:
let Numbers = Application("Numbers");
now kicks out an error "Application is not defined".
Is there a package I need to install via npm or some other syntax I need to utilize to make this script work?

Chris

Below is the beginning of my code:

```
let Numbers = Application("Numbers");

let allHistory = Numbers.documents[0].sheets[1].tables["All History"];

let principalData = Numbers.documents[0].sheets[2].tables["Principal"]; 

const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

let tempArray = [];
const principalDateArray = [];
const principalValueArray = [];

let rl = readline.createInterface({

    input: fs.createReadStream('../CSV/largecap.csv')

});

rl.on('line', function(line) {

    tempArray = line.split(',');
    principalDateArray.push(tempArray[0]);
    principalValueArray.push(tempArray[1]);

});

let arrayLength = principalDateArray.rows.Length;

for(let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){

    principalData.rows[i].cells[2].value = principalDateArray[i];
    principalData.rows[i].cells[3].value = principalValueArray[i];    

}
```

Comment: The visual studio code tag should be removed because it is not relevant to the question.